# extracting variables from a json

Tags: php, json

Assuming I have a json file looking like:

```
  {  
   "query":[  
      {  
         "pid":"abc"
      },
      {  
         "status":"cde"
      },
      {  
         "uname":"{{user->username}}"
      },
      {  
         "pass":"{{user->password}}"
      }
   ]
}
```

Assuming I convert this into a php array using `json_decode`, what is the simplest way to extract the values in between `{{` like variables? the rest of the array is constans.

Or maybe there is a tool for putting dynamic variables/params into a json file, and extracting them easily into php....

I am using Laravel 5.1 as a framework. The intention is configuration system, for setting up API connections to different APIs `(serviceabs.json,serviceefg.json)` , to fetch different datas from them. Now these APIs have different authentication mechanisms....and also I do not want to put this confidential data into the json file, but "inject" it.....then when the data is ready, use guzzle client to setup a connection. (after filling in username, password...etc)

so for example, this "query" array here, will be used as a GET Query for the guzzle client.

Comment: Might be an XY-problem: why is there `{{user->username}}` in the json doc in the first place?

Comment: it will be used to be filled in by a user, but the json offers a general settings of an external API we connect with using guzzle. the sensitive data I want to be filled in by user (on the fly), and not put into the json.

Comment: "I want to be filled in by user (on the fly)" - and somehow this "on-the-fly" input is then stored in `$user->prop`? Is it always `$user->`, or sometimes `$session->`? How does the input mechanism work? And how'd you limit the (let's call it what it is: ) templating system to only the variables the user should have access to?

Comment: And why are you assuming `$user` will exist, and be set to the correct instance when you `json_decode` this data? Besides, processing json data is something that is, by its very nature, likely to be done in loops and/or recursive functions (so the scope tends to change a lot). Resolving strings like `{{user->data->personal->email}}` is again something that will require recursion, or at least parsing, a safe way to resolve names, and a lot of looping

Comment: what might help would be to know, how you intend to use the output and if you're using a framework or something. Because this sounds like a job for a parser like twig or blade.

Comment: thanks, i extended my discription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be optimized but try:

```
$in = "hello {{world}} I am a {{fox}} my name is {{user->username}}";
preg_match_all('/\{\{([A-Za-z0-9 ->]+?)\}\}/', $in, $out);
print_r($out[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => world [1] => fox [2] => user->username )
```

Your case should be:

```
$in = '{{user->username}}';
preg_match_all('/\{\{([A-Za-z0-9 ->]+?)\}\}/', $in, $out);
if(isset($out[1])) {
    //there are matched within brackets 
    echo $out[1][0];  // will output: user->username
}
```

Comment: That covers part of the question. OK `$out[1]` is `user->username`, and now ...?